# Creating a custom collection view layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am attempting to create a collection view that looks like the schematic below. The centre item will always have 'focus' and be larger, its quite a bit like the cover flow concept:

http://s13.postimg.org/n6vzil213/layout_schematic.png

I can achieve this with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout, but I want the bottom cell (3) to animate larger and the middle cell (2) to animate smaller as I scroll? I assume I need to do some math with the scroll view delegate methods.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Does it need to be a collection view? Could you use a TableView instead?

Comment: Yes it should be a collection view, table views do not provide the animation capabilities like a collection view.

Comment: Table views have animation capabilities too. What animations exactly do you think you need that you won't have?

Comment: I'd rather leave the door open with a collection view since its a lot easier to swap out the layout later, and they just provide a lot more flexibility.

Comment: I don't really think it matters if you use a UITableView or UICollectionView. And I don't think you need to achieve this (necessarily) with a UICollectionViewLayout (or UICollectionViewFlowLayout for that matter). Why don't you subclass some UICollectionViewCells?

Comment: Well I will subclass UICollectionViewCell for sure, but how does that help with the layout?

Comment: How could I achieve this affect with a table view? Ultimately if it looks right I will be happy.

Comment: Do you want the edges of the cells to align perfectly like they do in the picture at all times? Or do you want overlapping like cover flow?

Comment: Overlapping would be a really nice touch, but definitely not required right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with only subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass
2. Override shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange: and return YES
3. Override layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: and layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:. Call the super implementation to get the standard FlowLayout values.
4. Create a method that both the methods from step #3 call that looks changes the layout attributes of the items based on their distance away from the center of the collection view's center. Use math to set the correct itemSize / transform / 3D transform for the items.

Here's a super rough example that sort of does what you're looking for, without the correct math.

```
@implementation MMLayout

-(CGSize)itemSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(200.0f, 200.0f);
}

-(BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *atts in attributes) {
        [self scaleForPositionOfAttributes:atts];
    }

    return attributes;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *atts = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self scaleForPositionOfAttributes:atts];

    return atts;
}

- (void)scaleForPositionOfAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attributes
{
    CGFloat collectionViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.bounds);
    CGFloat collectionViewCenter = collectionViewHeight / 2.0f;

    CGFloat scaleForCenter = ABS(collectionViewCenter - (attributes.frame.origin.y - self.collectionView.contentOffset.y)) < 50.0f ? 1.3f : 0.7f;
    attributes.size = CGSizeMake(200.0f * scaleForCenter, 200.0f * scaleForCenter);
}

@end
```

Comment: It turns out that this didn't really give the effect I wanted, I believe that what I want needs to be done in the collectionView's scrollViewDidScroll: by playing with transforms?

Comment: You can do that in here as well. The cell attributes have transform and 3Dtransform. You can get the current scroll position by accessing self.collectionview.contentoffset. I didn't work out all of the transform/item size details but alluded that you would need to fine tune that aspect to your liking.

Comment: Well I tried to make it work, I definitely got it closer, but Ive put in like 9 or 10 hours and I still can't get it there. maybe I will opt for something simpler.

Comment: I am having trouble with the edge cases (first and last cell). My diagram may have been a bit off. The very first cell of the view should be the "focus view" and then it should be the middle cell as you scroll. Also, when the size increases it is overlapping the other cells (it turns out I can't have it overlapping)

Comment: Also, I am not aware if it is possible to animate this at all, since it is sort of a harsh transition from the small cell to the large cell?

Comment: Well again, I wouldn't start exactly with the code I provided. You would want to determine the distance of the cell from the center of the screen and proportionally change the amount you are scaling the transform/itemSize/whatever. Psuedo-code scaleForCenter = 1 - abs(collection view center y - (cell center - scrollView.contentOffset)) / collection view center y; To adjust for the edge cases, when you are scrolled near the top or bottom, change the point you are considering the 'center' of the scrollView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59211/discussion-between-acey-and-dboyer).